Issue with installing Spark on windows
Windows 11
Spark -> C:\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7 
Winutils -> C:\winutils 
Java -> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22.0.1

I downloaded the above versions, created env variables,
HADOOP_HOME ='c:\\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7' , 

JAVA_HOME = 'c:\\winutils', 

SPARK_HOME = 'c:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-22.0.1'

and added these paths to both system and user variables
I have checked the env and sure they are available in path (both system and user). I am facing following issue while running spark shell:
C:\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>spark-shell
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.spark.unsafe.array.ByteArrayMethods.<clinit>(ByteArrayMethods.java:54)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:1006)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.$anonfun$loadEnvironmentArguments$3(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.loadEnvironmentArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$3.<init>(SparkSubmit.scala:990)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:990)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long,int)
        at org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:62)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long,int)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3784)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2955)
        at org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:55)
        ... 13 more


I think the version of spark which you are using is not supporting Java 22.
Go through the official documentation of the spark to check which version of java supported by the spark.

it's jdk 8 that should be used, but they should also look at upgrading to a later spark version if possible 3.0 is quite old now.
